# protect your server session

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, windows-server

Routinely someone takes over my session on a windows server after I disconnect but leave a calculation (that takes a longer time) running and closes my programs. 
We are using the same username on the server, however clients are distinguishable by clientname (visible e.g. in taskmanager).

1. Is there a way to protect my session (preferably without server admin privileges)?
2. What would be the easiest way of notifying me (e.g. via email) which clientname took over my session?

Comment: The proper method is to simply stop sharing the user account.

Comment: Indeed, however I cannot change how the system is set up